# Partial derivative notation extreme gradient boosting

Tags: boosting, notation

What is meant by this notation regarding gradient boosting [source](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/model.html):

$$
g_i = \partial_{\hat{y}_i^{(t-1)}} l(y_i, \hat{y}_i^{(t-1)})
$$

Is it the partial derivative of $l$ w.r.t. $\hat{y}_i^{(t-1)}$ , i.e.:

$$
g_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{y}_i^{(t-1)}} l(y_i, \hat{y}_i^{(t-1)})
$$

Comment: My assumption seems correct as per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#D-notation)

Comment: This is a common notation used in pdes: $\partial_x f\equiv \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}.$